# Can't Find any online documentation for MySQL c++ connector API

Tags: c++, mysql

I started working on mysql c++ connector API. 
But I can't find any online documentation for the API , I can only find example. 
Is there any link (or hidden way using doxygen) to generate documentation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-connector-cpp.html Would be most suitable for this.

Comment: It is not what , I was looking for. 
but can't find any link better than that.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same difficulties trying to find the documentation, but [somewhere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-cpp.html) in the MySQL docs I found that the MySQL C++ Connector was designed to be compatible with the JDBC 4.0 API.

> The MySQL Connector/C++ is compatible with the JDBC 4.0 API. However, MySQL Connector/C++ does not implement all of the JDBC 4.0 API methods.

Approximately 80% percent of the methods should work. That API can be found [here](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221).

Answer (score 0):

I could not find it either. An extremely strange and professional outrage!

Looks like this complain should be put in front of the guys at MySQL. The best page I found is **[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-getting-started-examples.html)**.

Further APIs can be studied from the list produced by smart editors using 
the completion attribute.

Sometimes that's the price of using community SW. :-)